# GLS vs ML in Linear Mixed Model

Tags: regression, mixed-model

Hox's Multilevel Analysis: Techniques and Applications states,

"Generalized Least Squares(GLS) estimates can be obtained from a Maximum Likelihood procedure by restricting the number of iterations to one."

I cant figure how it is so.

First of all, he doesn't state whether it's about ML or REML.

Second, as far as I know GLS is for error-variance-covariance structure.
I know random intercept model has a equivalent model with fixed coefficients and
error variance-covariance structure but I don't think it's possible
for all Mixed model to have equivalent model with fixed coefficients and error variance-covariance structure. Is it right? or wrong?

So anyone can elaborate on them?

Comment: It's very difficult to determine what it is you are asking here.  I'd recommend rephrasing this and providing more detail.

Comment: Well, it's just that i cant understand how "Generalized Least Squares(GLS) estimates can be obtained from a Maximum Likelihood procedure by restricting the number of iterations to one." is true. As far as I know, GLS is for the model without random effect... so how is it the ML with just one iteration is GLS???

Comment: Of course we are talking about multilevel(mixed effect) model...

Comment: Got it.  See my response below.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum Likelihood procedures (like those in SAS) typically use as starting values, the OLS parameter estimates, so that is why setting iteration to 1 would work here.